# angular drag and drop reusable components

Tags: node.js, angular, drag-and-drop, angular-dragdrop, angulardraganddroplists

In [this angular drag and drop](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vbgjymlmkvj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-overview-example.ts) example the component is just moving

But I need to keep the original file and generate N number of copies and move them.

I need the test box in the left and draggable for n number of times.[example](https://formio.github.io/ngFormBuilder/)